# SharePoint 2013 listview search box doesn't show particular result

Tags: 2013, list-view, search-results

I have a view in SharePoint 2013 list which has more than 5000 items with throttling disabled on the list. The view is grouped by a site column. The site column exists as a managed property and is marked searchable, queryable and retrievable in the schema. The problem is when I type in a search phrase in the list view, a particular phrase doesn't return any results. May be I should provide an example to illustrate:

1. So, the site column has these values: A, B, C, D
2. The view is grouped by this site column so I have different groups for A, B, C, D
3. When I search for "A" correct results are returned. Same for C and D.
4. However, when I search "B" either nothing gets returned or a partial set gets returned.

Further finding is that the list items where site column==B are more than 100 (if that matters which I don't think it should), AND the content itself is indexed.

I checked everywhere and was just thinking of checking if the trim duplicates might be causing it. However, because it is a list view search box I don't have access to that option.

Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: Is there no insight into this? Any suggestions?